# C++ Sending DateTime object to SQL using C++

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, visual-studio, datetime

I used simple code to pass DateTime object to MySQL in Visual Studio using C++ but I'm getting "incorrect datetime value". My guess is that it is because of DateTime format which is YYYY.MM.DD HH:MM:SS instead YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS that SQL is expecting.
Here is the code:

```
DateTime^ reservation = Convert::ToDateTime(date_w + " " + hour_w);

            query_r->CommandText = "INSERT INTO gabinet.visits SET clients_id="+id_client+", services_id="+id_services+", iduser="+userid+", r_from= '"+reservation+"', r_until='" + reservation+ "', status = 'AWAITS'; ";
            query_r->ExecuteNonQuery();
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: it's just a simple as using `reservation.ToString("yyyy-MM-DD [....]")` check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: I had to use `reservation->ToString("yyyy-MM-DD [....]") ` but your answer got me on a good track. Thanks a lot!

Comment: indeed i mixed up C# syntax with C++ syntax..